# AWS policy: need explanation for the "ForAllValues" qualifier

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have this SCP attached to account A in my org:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
          "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSetsRecordTypes": [
            "A",
            "AAAA"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As I understand:

- the SCP will deny if each and every record's type in my request equals A or AAAA
- the SCP will not deny if at least one record's type in my request is not equal A or AAAA

However, when I create R53 records in account A using the console:

[image]

The SCP still blocks the request even though the request contains a record of type "CNAME" which is not A or AAAA.

What is wrong in my understanding of this "ForAllValues" ? Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Do any of the `SCP effects on permissions` section from 
 the docs apply? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html

Comment: I am not sure of the details of the setup (remember that you have to have an actual IAM policy attached, in addition to scp, btw). But if what you want is "allow any request that has at least one not A/AAAA record type" (which is really odd but you do you), you could make an `allow` policy with `ForAnyValue: StringNotEquals`. Though, in any way, that policy seems really odd security-wise: you _can_ change A/AAAA records... as long as you change some other record with them?